# return the next MAX date less than a given date oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this query:

```
select inv_job.job_id,
       max( bh_invoice_smy.invoice_date) as d_invoice_date
from job

join job inv_job on job.job_id = inv_job.invoice_job_id
join customer on customer.cus_id = inv_job.cus_id
join organization_unit on organization_unit.ou_id = inv_job.ou_id
left outer join bh_invoice_smy on bh_invoice_smy.job_id = job.job_id

where
to_date(bh_invoice_smy.invoice_date,'YYYY/MM/DD') <= to_date( 'INPUTDATE','YYYY/MM/DD')

group by inv_job.job_id
```

I am trying to have it return the last d_invoice_date that is less than the INPUTDATE, currently this just omits d_invoice_date that is greater than INPUTDATE. For posting purposes, I have also omitted about 15 other predicates in the where clause none of which should affect the outcome of d_invoice_date.

I have looked at many posts with subquerys and inner joins but I cannot seem to get the solution.

Comment: what's the issue here? It will omit an invoice_date greater than you INPUTDATE coz of your `WHERE` CLAUSE. What is you expected Output?

Comment: basically, I would want to do this ... SELECT, JOB_ID, max(bh_invoice_smy.invoice_date) <  INPUTDATE

Comment: So why is your posted query not sufficient?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't want to omit those records that are less than INPUTDATE, i would like to retrieve the records that has an d_invoice_date <= INPUTDATE, so basically the next record that fits the criteria that is less than INPUTDATE, if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT Dt 
FROM Tbl
WHERE Dt < InputDate AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY Dt DESC
```

Comment: I believe ROWNUM is the Oracle equivalent.

Comment: This doesn't produce the results I am looking for. Am i supposed to be using this as a subquery in my Select? My issue is I need to figure it out some kind of clause that would limit returning invoice dates in the future or a given input date.